# Creating a backup batch file for backing up my programming code

Tags: c#, batch-file, backup

Just been reading through the questions that other people have been asking about batch files, and can't find anything useful.

I am wanting to backup all of my c# code, using a batch file. Please help me to find out what I am doing wrong?

This is what I am asking my batch file to run:

```
copy C:\Visual Studio Express\Test Programs\Program 1\ c:\Backup Code\
```

Everytime I find some code on google, it shows something like this:

```
copy C:\Fred\*.exe g:
```

Now that is useless to me, as I tried that, and that code has got no spaces in, like mine does.

If you can help me out, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
copy "C:\Visual Studio Express\Test Programs\Program 1\" "c:\Backup Code\"
```

That said, you can run a source control repository locally, take a look at [this tutorial](http://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/setup-svn-local-repository-step-by-step/) for some information on how to setup a "local" SVN source control repository. This can function as a backup and has the added advantage of giving you a **history** of backups.

Comment: Awesome, thanks mate! I remember now, in c# - if you have space is a line of text, you stick quotes on either side. Thanks again for that!

Comment: @Rob: +1, great minds and all.  I prefer a local repro to a public one anyhow, so your answer has the edge :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use quotes around your filenames:

```
copy "C:\Visual Studio Express\Test Programs\Program 1\" "c:\Backup Code\"
```

(though I think you'll want to use `xcopy` or copy `...Program 1\*.*` for this to work properly)

Also, if you can stand it being public, a much better way to back up your source code is to use a free version control system, such as GitHub:

https://github.com/

They will allow you to keep a history of your changes, and allow you to roll back to previous versions.  This will become very helpful at some point :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your paths in quotes if you are having white spaces:

```
copy "C:\Visual Studio Express\Test Programs\Program 1\" "c:\Backup Code\"
```

But instead of copying your project you should really consider using a source code management system like [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) or [something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software).

Answer (score 1):

Just quote your paths:

```
copy "C:\Visual Studio Express\Test Programs\Program 1\" "c:\Backup Code\"
```

I also recommend you to check out [xcopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY) instead of copy. It allows some more useful operations.

Answer (score 0):

You problably need to wrap paths that contains spaces with `""`

```
copy C:\"Visual Studio Express"\"Test Programs"\"Program 1"\ c:\"Backup Code"\
```